# SNMP: No such object available on this agent at this OID

Tags: snmp, oid

I am trying to monitor the state of a UPS (NetVision), using the provided mib file.
So, upsBatteryStatus should be .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1.0

**snmpwalk -c COMMUNITY -v1 192.168.1.10 .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1.0**
iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1.0 = INTEGER: 2

And here comes the tricky part:

**snmptranslate -Of SOCOMECUPS-MIB::upsBatteryStatus**
.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.socomecSicon.software.network.netvision.upsObjects.upsBattery.upsBatteryStatus

**snmptranslate -On SOCOMECUPS-MIB::upsBatteryStatus**
.1.3.6.1.4.1.4555.1.1.1.1.2.1
Its different from .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1.0 , and it doesnt respond with a value.

**check_snmp -H 192.168.1.10 -C COMMUNITY -o upsBatteryStatus -w 1 -c @3:7 -m /var/lib/mibs/ietf/NetVision-nv6-unix.mib  -l "Battery Status: "**

External command error: Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: SOCOMECUPS-MIB::upsBatteryStatus

Any ideas why it isnt recongnizes as upsBatteryStatus ?

Comment: "So, upsBatteryStatus should be .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1.0" Where did you get that information? Clearly, the MIB disagrees.

Comment: If I snmpwalk the OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1.0 I get a valid reply. On the other hand, I get nothing for .1.3.6.1.4.1.4555.1.1.1.1.2.1 !

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 2 objects with the object name upsBatteryStatus in 2 different MIBs:  http://www.oidview.com/mibs/4555/SOCOMECUPS-MIB.html and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1628 . That explains the different OIDs. Nothing wrong with that. The OID is the true identifier of an object, the name is just for us humans.

As far as the error, I don't know what check_snmp does, so cannot say anything about that. But, have you tried this command?

snmpwalk -c COMMUNITY -v1 192.168.1.10 .1.3.6.1.4.1.4555.1.1.1.1.2.1

Comment: Yes, correct. But I get nothing for .1.3.6.1.4.1.4555.1.1.1.1.2.1 ! According to the manufacture this should be the correct oid.

Comment: _"Nothing wrong with that"_ Untrue, you cannot legally reuse names, and this is exactly why. See RFC 2578 3.6. SOCOMECUPS should have been called something else to disambiguate the new/replacement MIB.

Comment: Actually the MIB you link to is UPS-MIB, not SOCOMECUPS-MIB.

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE to guarantee uniqueness of descriptors over all MIBs in the face of decentralized registrations. That's why they allow collisions, ie. your RFC 2578 3.2. They just mandate uniqueness within a MIB and for standard MIBs, ie. your RFC 2578 section 3.1. That's why there is nothing wrong with it. Also, I reference 2 links to 2 different MIBs in my answer.

Comment: @ampratino we have seen devices where the private MIB cannot be accessed with the public community. Make sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful commands:

snmptranslate -Tp -m  /usr/share/mibs/ietf/NetVision-nv6-unix.mib

and:

"upsBatteryStatus"                      "1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.1"

```
        |        |  |
        |        |  +--upsBattery(2)
        |        |  |  |
        |        |  |  +-- -R-- EnumVal   upsBatteryStatus(1)
        |        |  |  |        Values: unknown(1), batteryNormal(2), batteryLow(3), batteryDepleted(4)
```

Nagios check_snmp command that reported the correct value is:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_snmp -H 192.168.1.10 -C COMMUNITY -m /var/lib/mibs/ietf/NetVision-nv6-unix.mib -o upsBatteryStatus -w @0:1 -c @3:7 -l "Battery Status: "
SNMP OK - Battery Status:  2 | 'Battery Status: '=2;1;7;
```

Thank you for help.